# want to give a fix position to button and list text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
function enterToSubmit(event){
  var key = event.keyCode;
  if(key===13){
      add();
  }
}
function get_todos() {
var todos = new Array;
var todos_str = localStorage.getItem('todo');
if (todos_str !== null) {
    todos = JSON.parse(todos_str); 
}
return todos;
}

function add() {
var task = document.getElementById('task').value;

var todos = get_todos();
todos.push(task);
localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));

show();

return false;
}

function remove() {
var id = this.getAttribute('id');
var todos = get_todos();
todos.splice(id, 1);
localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));

show();

return false;
}

function show() {
var todos = get_todos();

var html = '<ul>';
for(var i=0; i<todos.length; i++) {
    html += '<li>' + todos[i] + '<button class="remove" id="' + i  + '">x</button></li>';
};
html += '</ul>';

document.getElementById('todos').innerHTML = html;

var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', remove);
};
}

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', add);
show();
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
#a{
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lime;
}
input:focus{
  border-color: aqua;
}
input{
  margin: 30px 0px 30px 30px;
  border-radius: 35%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: aqua;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 64);
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
#add,button{
  font-size: large;
  border-radius: 30%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 64);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#todos{
}
button{
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-left: 18px;
}
li{
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>TODO List</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="nv.css">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="a">
        <input id="task" onkeypress="enterToSubmit(event)"><button id="add">Add</button>
      </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="todos">

    </div>
    <script src="nv.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am making a todo list wab app in javascript html and css and when i insert any element or task it take position according to length of task but i want all button and task in a parallel line

---

HTML Code :- https://textuploader.com/1oyu3

---

CSS Code :- https://textuploader.com/1oyuy

---

JS Code :- https://textuploader.com/1oyui

---

Img:-[current img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auROp.png)

---

Img:-[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/251PE.png)

---

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you can see full at  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v4owmxrj/1/)

i add div at your javascript

```
for(var i=0; i<todos.length; i++) {
    html += '<li><div class="list">' + todos[i] + '</div><div class="button"><button class="remove" id="' + i  + '">x</button></div></li>';
};
```

and make add css with class list & button

```
.list{
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
}
.button{
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: right;
}
li{
display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change nv.js

```
function enterToSubmit(event){
   var key = event.keyCode;
   if(key===13){
      add();
   }
}
function get_todos() {
    var todos = new Array;
    var todos_str = localStorage.getItem('todo');
    if (todos_str !== null) {
       todos = JSON.parse(todos_str); 
    }
    return todos;
 }

  function add() {
     var task = document.getElementById('task').value;

     var todos = get_todos();
     todos.push(task);
     localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));

     show();

      return false;
   }

   function remove() {
        var id = this.getAttribute('id');
        var todos = get_todos();
        todos.splice(id, 1);
        localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));

        show();

        return false;
  }

  function show() {
        var todos = get_todos();

        var html = '<ul>';
        for(var i=0; i<todos.length; i++) {
            html += '<li><span class="todoname">' + todos[i] + '</span><button class="remove" id="' + i  + '">x</button></li>'; // add span in name for css
        };
        html += '</ul>';

        document.getElementById('todos').innerHTML = html;

        var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
        for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i].addEventListener('click', remove);
        };
   }

   document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', add);
   show();
```

nv.css

```
li{
     font-size: 25px;
     border: 10px solid black;
     margin: 5px;
     padding: 5px;
     height:50px;   // add height in li
}

/* add this classes in your css */
.remove
{
    float:right;
}

.todoname
{
    margin-left: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```